# Changing Product Options Layout in Magento

Tags: magento, php

How do you change the layout of the product options box? I have created a Configurable product with color options.

I notice that Magento demo store doesn’t display the product options consistently.

My options box appears spanning the entire column for what is just a 1 character choice.

I would like the options to display at the very least like this product:
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt-1.html

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: my current layout looks like this: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/asicsr-men-s-gel-kayanor-xii.html

Answer (score 4):

@Joseph's answer will help with cosmetic styling, but if you need to edit the markup, then you'll need the template files in 
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle\option\` and depending on your configuration, edit `checkbox.phtml`, `radio.phtml`, `select.phtml`, etc.

Don't forget to copy the files into your local theme path for upgrade-safe edits.

Cheers,
Jonathan

Comment: I know this is 4 years old, know any reason why it doesn't affect whenever I override the checkbox.phtml?

When I added a die in the base for testing it would still show the options.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're having trouble w/ the CSS for the options. If that's the case, try changing to the following style rule:

```
.product-options dd select {
    width:auto;
}
```

That will make select boxes take only the minimum necessary space to display their options. Be aware that the previous rule (`width:99%`) is there for visual consistency so your options may look ragged this way.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank you guys.  By using firebug, I realized that I just needed to move the production-option codes within the product-shop div (I am not sure if I am saying it right).  And it was done.  Thank you once again!